# What is the name of manga where the Main Character gets bored in his own world due to him being the strongest and uses reincarnation magic

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I'm looking for a manga where the main character gets bored in his own world due to him being the strongest and uses reincarnation magic.

Comment: Hello, please refer to the [story identification checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and give us as many more details as you can. Also remember it's just one question per post here. Please take our [tour] and read the [help] for guidance, then [edit] your question to fit the site's ways.

Comment: Hi I've removed the second question here, we have a strict policy on one question per post. The logic is that as soon as somebody identifies your story, you can mark the question as correct. Please do though ask another question here, once of course, you've followed the links A Rogue Ant has supplied you with.

Comment: I think there's quite a few manga with the basic premise of "reached the limit of their power and reincarnated to grow further". Do you have more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might this be ***[The Second Life Cheat Reincarnation Mage - If the Strongest Reincarnated After 1000 Years, Life Would Be Too Easy](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=171646)***...?

> **Having become overwhelming strong, a mage was bored with his life and decided to reincarnate in another era about 1000 years later.**
>
> But after reincarnation, the mage now known as Kurt saw a world where magic had declined, and the mages of the era are overall much weaker than those of 1000 years ago.
>
> It also seems that Kurt is being looked down upon for his "Gold Magic" as it is called "Defective Magic Power" in this era.
>
> In order to investigate the mysterious decline of magic in this era, Kurt enrolled in the Magic Academy at the Royal Capital and showed his extraordinary talent where he would become unparalleled in this second life of his too!?

[image]